# SQL Server symmetric key & certificates games by Hacker?

Tags: sql-server, security

1)

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SecureSymmetricKey
    WITH ALGORITHM = DESX
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = N'StrongPassword';
```

I'm trying to figure out about the SQL Server encryption.

- once I've executed the code above, is there any way to find out later what is the password value for the `SecureSymmetricKey` ?

2)

If now I'm doing this with `Certificates` : I`m the admin and created:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION
BY PASSWORD = 'DB Master key password!'
GO
```

only I know the password.

later I :

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE MyCertificate
WITH SUBJECT = 'My Certificate Subject'

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY MySymetricKey
WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE MyCertificate
```

until now , Its all ok.

Now, when a **hacker** comes to the computer, all **he** has to do **is** :

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MySymetricKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE MyCertificate
```

and then :

```
SELECT  
       convert( NVARCHAR(max), decryptbykey(namePAss)) 
FROM  tbl1
```

so where is the protection in certificates? No one asked him for a password (like in password encryption (as in my first question)...? He only needed to know the certificate name

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MySymetricKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE MyCertificate
```

and its not a problem to find out what is the certificate name ...**So where is the protection in decypher data from the hacker ?**

Comment: I am really not sure what your question is exactly ?

Comment: @Yahia : step by step : lets talk about 1) once the admin executed these lines. Is there any command that he would be able to find what is the passowrd which was used to encrypt ? ( cause a hacker can write : `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SecureSymmetricKey
 DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = N'StrongPassword';
` and then see the data....

Comment: you write "a hacker can..." - security is a multi-level process and these measures you describe are only one part of many... and when one wants to check security one needs some scenario for that... you neither provide a scenario nor a security architecture... thus making it impossible to a give a real answer...

Comment: @Yahia , what about if hacker got my sql db into his hands (this is the scenario)...Is there any command that he would be able to find what is the passowrd which was used to encrypt ??

Comment: A good tutorial on SQL Server encryption: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/

Comment: @Rick all day long ive been practicing on this page and therefor i had some conceptual questions...

Comment: @Rick  If I used certificate , The hacker can see wheich certificates are installed ,  and by the code : `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MySymetricKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE MyCertificate` he can see the real data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a certificate in SQL Server is to protect the symmetric keys, but it's more for protecting your offline data: .mdb files and backups.  It's not really designed for preventing access to the data once an attacker has access to the running SQL instance (with enough permission to access the data and run decryption.)

- If you use a *password* for your symmetric key, then someone who knows or can guess the password can take a copy of your data and load and decrypt it.
- If you use a *certificate*, then the attacker needs a copy of the data, and a backup of the certificate, and the password for the certificate.

Comment: listen man you are awesome . question :  for the code `CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SecureSymmetricKey
    WITH ALGORITHM = DESX
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = N'StrongPassword';` , is there any way by sql select command to see the N'StrongPassword' from  SecureSymmetricKey ?

Comment: I don't think so; I think it's hashed with a seed, so even attacks with a rainbow table against the hash would be difficult.  I can't find the BOL reference right now, but that's always been my understanding (and it wouldn't make much sense to store it plaintext!)

Comment: I wish to thank you a lot. ( if i'll have more advanced sql question i'll ask you directly :)  ) . thanks.

Comment: but If I used certificate , The hacker can see wheich certificates are installed ,  and by the code : `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MySymetricKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE MyCertificate` he can see the real data...

Comment: Yes, but he would need access to the running SQL instance, using an account that has permission to query the data and that has permission to run the decryption.  If you use Windows security (e.g.: Active Directory groups) and grant minimal permission to the accounts, you should keep your attack surface fairly small.

Comment: 'using an account that has permission to query the data' you mean the `SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys` query ?

Comment: I meant having SELECT permission on the table or view whose data you are encrypting (assuming you're not going for full database encryption.)  So the attacker needs to have a valid logon for the SQL server instance, that logon needs CONTROL permission on the certificate, and that logon also needs SELECT permission on the object(s) being queried.

Comment: what is the sql permission name required for 'open symetric key ' && use the certificate ?

Comment: I think you just want to grant "CONTROL" permission to the user.  I don't see any fixed server or database level roles that include CONTROL permission, except for "db_owner".  You don't want to add logins to the db_owner role, for obvious reasons!